# Direct2D, WPF D3D10 image blurs on resizing

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, directx, direct2d

I am developing a WPF application which uses DirectX for drawing the background and border for my application. I have used a code from here : [Using Direct2D with WPF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113991/Using-Direct2D-with-WPF)

The Code works fine but when I draw a rectangle and doesn't fill the rectangle, during resize it blurs.
Here is the screenshot of the issue.

[image: Blur Issue Screenshot]

The red border around window is the rectangle that I have drawn. The only change that i have made to the code is given below:

```
protected override void OnRender() {
  // Calculate our actual frame rate
  this.frameCount++;
  if (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(this.time).TotalSeconds >= 1) {
    this.fps = this.frameCount;
    this.frameCount = 0;
    this.time = DateTime.UtcNow;
  }

  // This is what we're going to draw. We'll animate the width of the
  // elipse over a span of five seconds (ElapsedTime / 5).
  this.widthRatio += this.ElapsedTime / 5;
  if (this.widthRatio > 1) // Reset
  {
    this.widthRatio = 0;
  }

  var size = this.RenderTarget.Size;
  float width = (float)((size.Width / 3.0) * this.widthRatio);
  var ellipse = new D2D.Ellipse(new D2D.Point2F(size.Width / 2.0f, size.Height / 2.0f), width, size.Height / 3.0f);
  var rect = new D2D.RectF();
  rect.Height = size.Height;
  rect.Width = size.Width;
  rect.Top = 0;
  rect.Left = 0;
  // This draws the ellipse in red on a semi-transparent blue background
  this.RenderTarget.BeginDraw();
  this.RenderTarget.Clear(new D2D.ColorF(0, 0, 0, 1f));
  this.RenderTarget.FillEllipse(ellipse, this.redBrush);
  // Draw a little FPS in the top left corner
  string text = string.Format("FPS {0}", this.fps);
  this.RenderTarget.DrawRectangle(rect, redBrush, 10f);
  this.RenderTarget.DrawText(text, this.textFormat, new D2D.RectF(10, 10, 100, 20), this.whiteBrush);

  // All done!
  this.RenderTarget.EndDraw();
}
```

I Think the problem is caused by WPF being not able to resize the D3D10 Image at time of resizing. Is there any way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an answer it was simple. The Direct2D control is nothing but like an ordinary Image Control. the problem is that the image was not able to resize in time. I the given code the Image was resized using a `DispatcherTimer` which causes latency. so  i copied the code which is in the `ResizeTimerTick()` function to a new public function and called the function in `OnSizeChanged()` event on my window. Here is the code that i have used.

```
public void onResize() {
    if (this.Scene != null) {
        // Check we don't resize too small
        int width = Math.Max(1, (int) this.ActualWidth);
        int height = Math.Max(1, (int) this.ActualHeight);
        this.Scene.Resize(width, height);

        this.imageSource.Lock();
        this.imageSource.SetBackBuffer(this.Scene.Texture);
        this.imageSource.Unlock();

        this.Scene.Render();
    }
}
```

In The MainWindow.cs:

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
    d2DControl.onResize();
}
```

**Note: This method consumes a little bit of more memory (almost 74 MB)**